# Running a groovy script in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I'm currently writing some groovy scripts. Till now I simply use notepad and run the scripts via `groovy script.groovy`. But I'm looking some help for editing the files. So I tried eclipse with the groovy plugin which looks great...for groovy projects. But I just want to edit and run the groovy scripts. No Project dir etc.. What's the best way to handle scripts in eclipse. I don't want to package the files to jars or something like that. I have just a folder with some scripts in it... No src/bin directory or subfolders for package names. Is that possible?

Thanks,
Ingo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must convert your project to a Groovy project (right-click project: `Configure > Convert to Groovy Project`), but then, sure, it's possible.

When editing a `.groovy` file, select `Run > Run as ... > Groovy Script`

Comment: I tried that too. But I think that you need to have at least a java project. Otherwise I do not have the option to convert it to a groovy project...another anoying thing is that it always generates .class files which is messing up the script folder...but I think there is no way arund. Either code completion or a clean folder without .setting, .classpath, .project and class files.. Thank anyway.

Comment: Another thing that bugs me is that it's not possible to use packages without really moving the files to the correspondig subfolder. I know, it should be done that way but sometimes I just want to set a package name to work correctly with some predefined loggers...

Comment: All logging frameworks I know also accept a String parameter. e.g. `Logger.getLogger("foo.bar.MyClass")` would not require package `foo.bar`

Comment: You got me...it was/is a simple BasicLogger that was written by one of my colleages that only accept a class.;-)  But when we change that component it should work...it might be best to ask for a specific logger in that case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like Eclipse is a bit heavyweight for your needs, have you considered using the GroovyConsole instead? It's a very simple Groovy IDE, available in the Groovy `bin` directory. Assuming you have this directory on your `PATH`, you can start it by running `groovyConsole` from the command line.

Useful shortcuts are:

- Ctrl + R : run the script
- Ctrl + W : clear the output

Comment: Hi. Yeah I tried that already and it works quite okay. But the groovyconsole does not provide much more than a good texteditor (like Notepad++). No codecompletion or syntax check while editing...

Answer (score 0):

This solution still requires a "project", but aims to use Eclipse to do it in the least invasive way.

http://andrewclement.blogspot.com/2009/12/using-eclipse-to-edit-your-groovy.html#!/2009/12/using-eclipse-to-edit-your-groovy.html

Then you can use the "run as" as stated by Mr. Floyd :D